# OOP Best Practice for Objects containing other objects

Tags: java, oop, extends

I keep struggling with the best way to implement this. Let's say I have two objects, one is a user object the other is a note object. The Note object will hold notes for a patient and it will store who created the note and who it was last updated by. What is the better option:

**Option A** - Two objects, one with just the Note specific info and the other an extension of this object with the User objects for patient/author/updater:

```
public class Note {
    private int noteId;
    private int patientId;
    private int authorId;
    private int updatedById;
    private String noteText;
    private Date noteDate;
}

public class NoteExt extends Note {
    private User patient;
    private User author;
    private User updater;
}
```

**Option B** - One Note object with User classes for patients, author, updater

```
public class Note {
    private int noteId;
    private User patient;
    private User author;
    private User updater;
    private String noteText;
    private Date noteDate;
}
```

Option A would bloat the application with a ton of files for the additional objects/db calls but would speed things up when getting lists of items. (Also is it correct to use extend in this case?)

Option B would mean not worrying about remembering which object to use when and only having one database function, but would repeat data if, for example, I were getting a list of all notes a user has created.

Is there an option C that's better??

Comment: Will you need to find notes belonging to specific patients? Does a patient have more than one note? Same question for author and updater. In which direction will you be traversing the relationship?

Comment: So a patient can have multiple notes created by multiple people and yes I will need to find all notes for a specific patient. But you can also view an author's profile and see all notes they've written for different patients.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't base the DB on your data structures directly.  How your arrange the data in Java and how you arrange it in the DB  don't have to be the same and what makes sense for one may not make sense for the other.

Comment: Well the thing is this question also applies to pretty much every other object in the application. Another example is facilities and regions. Looking up individual facilities will show region it's in. Looking up a region will show all facilities within the region. But if I'm adding/editing a facility it really only needs regionId and likewise if I'm adding/editing a region I don't need to know which facilities are in that region.

Answer (score 2):

Plan C could be something like this. Creating all objects as separate entities with one composite. Making the note more reusable for other applications.

```
public class Note {
    private int noteId;
    private String noteText;
    private Date noteDate;
}

public class PatientNote {
    private Note note;
    private User patient;
    private User author;
    private User updater;
}
```

Comment: If I wanted to display a list of all notes by a specific author, would I then create another object AuthorNote with Note note, User patient and then an AuthorNotes class with properties User author and an ArrayList of AuthorNote?

Comment: In case of this `PatientNote` you just look it up by author. It will get you every `PatientNote` from that author with access to the `Note` object.

Comment: This answer offers a good alternative but all depends on how the relationships are to be traversed.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are confusing the object design with the database design. It's understandable since you are creating objects that need to be represented in a database. However, I found that in many cases, it's easiest to "forget" the database and just design your objects, then come back and create mappers for your objects using the model-mapper design pattern, adding unique id's as needed.

So you use option B, BUT for storing/loading to/from the database, you use separate mapper classes: i.e. UserMapper, NoteMapper, etc... The secret then is that the mapper uses an IdentityMap, so that when things are getting loaded by ID, a locally cached copy of an object is used rather than going to the database over and over to get the same user object for a userID (for instance).

```
public class Note {
    private int noteId;
    private User patient;
    private User author;
    private User updater;
    private String noteText;
    private Date noteDate;
}

public class UserMapper {
    public User getUserById(int userId){
        User user = UserIdentityMap.getUser(userId);
        if(user == null) {
            user = fetchUserFromDb(userId);
            UserIdentifyMap.cache(userId, user);
        }
        return user;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is interesting, I'm going to dig deeper into this. Any good resources you know of to get more info on this?

Comment: http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_mapper_pattern  but just google "data mapper" or "java data mapper pattern"

Answer (score 2):

Option B is correct. You should not think how data will be persisted when you model objects.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a relationship like that based on information you're retrieving from a database, especially *maintaining* such a relationship, and also ensuring referential integrity so that changes to one item propagate to the rest of them (if that's something you want, otherwise you run the risk of recreating numerous copies of the same record if you don't enforce it) can get pretty complicated.

It's probably just me, but the `NoteExt` class seems like it's kind of abusing inheritance here. The first class seems perfectly fine and simple to me, and I like simple. You'll probably have some database context class that the application can use to find a user or some other record based on its ID (e.g., `Database.userForId(int)`). To me it makes sense to keep things separated and simple by offering just the essentials, but still provide a way to easily request more information about a record.

As others have mentioned, there's several preexisting alternatives (e.g., Hibernate and JPA) which can map database objects for you and create the kind of relationships you desire.

To answer your question below, I think it's important to note that the ORMs we create aren't necessarily going to be the models we provide to our views--don't get me wrong, it'd be great if it were always that easy, but as you said, sometimes they require a bit more information (that might not even be related to the records from the database, but to the views themselves). In C#'s MVC framework we face a similar problem which a lot of us overcome by creating separate models specifically for our views, much like a `DefaultListModel` maintains a vector of data to be displayed in a `JList` (but the model itself doesn't extend `Vector` or any other collection). The new view model you create can then contain all of the necessary bits of information you'd like to display in the view, and also provide other methods for interacting with it and modifying it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer sbat. Follow up quesetion, since I'm using MVC, if I were displaying a list of all notes for a patient in the view and I only had that first class, how could I display the author's name since I didn't store it in the object? Would I need to create a hashmap or something with key's being authorId's?

Answer (score 0):

B is the usual way to do this, JPA has anticipated the problem:

- The EntityManager acts as an identity map and makes sure you don't have more than one copy of an object at a time, so that if you retrieve a list of notes by the same user, those will all be references to the same User object.
- the references to the other objects are lazy by default, you are getting back only a proxy that contains the ID, making the overhead equivalent to A.